# asymmetric Dual of the asymmetric Dual is Primal?

Tags: linear-programming, duality-theorems

It is known that in Linear Programming the Dual of the Dual is the Primal.

In wikipedia I saw that apart from the symmetric Dual I knew, there is also the asymmetric one:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_linear_program#Vector_formulations

I tried to show that the "Dual of the Dual is the Primal" would still hold in this case but I didn't manage to.

My question is: Does the "Dual of the Dual is the Primal" still holds for the asymmetric case? And if yes, could you please provide a comprehensive proof ?

Comment: There is a general dual problem construction for convex optimization problems that you should learn (see Boyd and Vandenberghe for example). In both the "symmetric" and "asymmetric" examples you mentioned, the dual problem given is just the plain old dual problem. So yes, the dual of the dual is the primal in either case, because that always happens when you form the dual of a convex optimization problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okey. I managed.

The asymmetric duality says:

**Primal** 
max ${c^Tx}$
s.t. $Ax ≤ b$

*produces the folowing*

**Dual**
min $b^Ty$
s.t. $A^Ty = c$
$y ≥ 0$

I want to prove that I can go back to Primal from the Dual applying only the knowledge of this asymmetric transformation.

First I need to bring the Dual in the 'standard' form as in Primal:
$$
max\; -b^Ty\\
s.t.\quad 
\begin{align}
   A^Ty & \le c\\
   -A^Ty & \le -c\\
   -y & \le 0\\
\end{align}\\
$$
$$
\implies
\begin{align}
max\; -b^Ty\\
s.t. \qquad \begin{bmatrix}A^T\\-A^T\\-I\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}y\\y\\y\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}c\\-c\\0\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
$$
Where $I$ is the identity matrix.
Applying the assymetric Dual transformation we get:
$$
min\; \begin{bmatrix}c^T & -c^T & 0\end{bmatrix}w\\
s.t.
\begin{align}
\quad \begin{bmatrix}A & -A & -I\end{bmatrix}w & = -b\\
w & \ge 0
\end{align}\\
$$
let $w = \begin{bmatrix}u & v & k\end{bmatrix}^T$. Then:
$$
min\; c^Tu -c^Tv\\
s.t.
\begin{align}
\quad Au -Av -Ik & = -b\\
u,v,k & \ge 0
\end{align}\\
$$
reforming:
$$
max\; c^T(v - u)\\
s.t.
\begin{align}
\quad A(v - u) & = b - Ik\\
u,v,k & \ge 0
\end{align}\\
$$
let $x = v-u$
$$
max\; c^Tx\\
s.t.
\begin{align}
\quad Ax & = b - Ik\\
k & \ge 0
\end{align}\\
$$
We no longer have guarantee for the sign of $x$.
Since $k \ge 0$ the Right Hand Side will be greater if we omit the last term:
$$
max\; c^Tx\\
s.t.
\begin{align}
\quad Ax \le b \\
\end{align}\\
$$
Which is exactly the Primal Problem.